# MS Acess Invalid or unqualified reference

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Currently I'm working on Access with importing external data from excel.I'm getting **Invalid or unqualified reference** when I'm trying to excess the value.

Column That Available in Excel Sheet:-

1. Group_Number
2. Card_Number

Below is the code that I have tried so far:-

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM " & _
      "tbl_mainframe "

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qry)

rst.MoveLast
total_record = rst.RecordCount
rst.MoveFirst

For i = 0 To total_record - 1
MsgBox (Nz(!Card_Number)) - > **Error**
rst.MoveNext
Next i
rst.Close
```

Please advise.

Comment: try nz(rst.card_number) instead

Comment: @SamM.. still getting error.. Member not found

Comment: If you use `qry = "SELECT Card_Number FROM tbl_mainframe"` what is the value of `total_record` and what does `MsgBox rst(0)` report?

Comment: @Jeeped,I'm getting 18 as the total record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work
`qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_mainframe"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qry)
do While not rst.Eof
MsgBox (Nz(rst!Card_Number)) 
rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close`